# Odoo database multiple condition AND and OR Android

Tags: android, odoo, xml-rpc

Hello every one i am using Odoo Database with Xmlrpc My current code is

```
 asList(asList(asList("state","=", "assigned")//here i need AND condetion
,asList(asList("groups_id","in",groupsId),"OR",asList("user_id","=",userId)))),
```

In above code here i want one AND condition with internal list and OR condition where i have put "OR". Please show me a correct way

Comment: Where you want "AND" condition ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 asList(
    asList(
        "&",
        asList("state","=", "assigned"),
        "|",
        asList(asList("groups_id","in",groupsId),
        sList("user_id","=",userId))
    )
 ),
```

Comment: Thanks i will try it

Comment: this is equal to `state == assinged and (group_ids in gourpsId or user_id == userId)` Is this how you want your condition to be?

Comment: i want asList("state","=", "assigned"),
        "&",
       ( asList(asList("groups_id","in",groupsId),"|"
        sList("user_id","=",userId)))

Comment: yeah this is what give you